# Qt Libraries cannot be found on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I'm having issues setting up the Qt environment on Mac 10.9.1. If I just try to compile a C++ file with the standard

```
 g++ source.cpp -o output
```

Then none of the Qt Libraries are found. For instance if I have

```
#include <QString>
```

Then I will get the error

```
fatal error: 'QString' file not found
```

I have installed Qt 5.2.1 and added it to my PATH variable, so now when i make the project using

```
qmake -project, qmake -spec macx-g++ and then make
```

I get the error saying that my version of Mac OSX is not supported. I have to use Qt for my college assignment, please can someone help me set this up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756694/qt-5-and-os-x-mavericks-issues) could be useful ;-)

Comment: Well, are previous version compatible with mavericks? I've just been searching around and I cant find much. Also, nowhere does it say how to remove a version of Qt that I've already installed. Problems.

Comment: Mavericks is supported by Qt 5.2.1. Which XCode do you have installed, and do you have the XCode CLI tools installed?

Comment: Not sure on the XCode version but I do have the CLI tools installed for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mavericks is definitely supported by Qt 5. It is not supported by Qt 4 so far; trojanfoe made a typo in his comment ([nomen est omen?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_determinism)).

Your mistake is using the wrong make spec. Qt 5 uses clang, not gcc. Thus the following works for me (without setting any paths):

```
~/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang_64/bin/qmake -project
~/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang_64/bin/qmake -spec macx-clang
make
```

You can have multiple Qt versions existing side by side, there's no reason to uninstall anything when you get a new Qt version installed.

A small self-contained example would be below. Put it in a `simple` folder. To build, do:

```
~/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang_64/bin/qmake -spec macx-clang
make
```

You do not want to regenerate the .pro file by invoking qmake with `-project` argument. The project generation is just to give you a simple skeleton, you're only supposed to do it as a convenience when importing third-party code.

Note that *by definition* if you use any visible GUI elements (windows, message boxes, etc), it's not a console application anymore as far as Qt is concerned.

```
# simple.pro
TEMPLATE = app
QT += widgets
# Creates a simple executable instead of an app bundle
CONFIG -= app_bundle
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMessageBox>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  // It is an error not to have an instance of QApplication.
  // This implies that having an instance of QCoreApplication and QGuiApplication
  // is also an error.
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QMessageBox::information(NULL, "Get This!", "Something's going on");
}
```

Comment: @nickcorin What "scripts" can't you run? You mean that you can't run the executable? Well, you simply have to give a full path to the executable. It's within the .app bundle. If those are console projects, then you have to edit the .pro file to make them so.

Comment: Yes, we're starting small so at the moment we are making console projects with maybe one or two QMessageBox's at the moment.

Comment: It seems that some of the libraries still cannot be found. QString and QTextStream work fine, but for instance QApplication cannot be found and neither can QMessageBox or QWidgets.

Comment: I've managed to get some of the libraries working by adding QT += widgets into my .pro file and running qmake again. Now every time I try run an application with a QMessageBox, the application immediately crashes with "Abort Trap: 6".

Comment: @nickorin You'd have to post a separate question with a minimal test case that demonstrates the crash. You need to show contents of both the .pro and main.cpp files.

Comment: Wow, my mind is burning with the thought that I should know so much about this before I can get everything up and running properly. Good luck to me! I'll post a separate question soon I think. Thank you for all your help.